# One page and auto link

Tags: contacts, profile, households

We have a volunteer organisation. Most of the volunteers are in thier 70's. Is there a way that CIVI can do the following using either a profile or a specific page that does the following sequence at once after data entry

1. Add the Household Contact and relevant fields
2. Adds a new individual for each household member
3. Adds the relationships for primary contact then household member(s)
4. Then adds the Household as a membership and save it all

Ok i hear you....am I drawing a very long bow?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like it will depend somewhat on your set up. If you're on Drupal, you could have a look into using [webform civicrm](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) which would be able to handle all of the above (creating the contacts, relationships, and membership). You could also do clever things like populate the name of the Household based on the Last name value entered for one of your contacts.

I'm not as familiar with the other CMS integrations but hopefully someone more versed in Wordpress or Joomla can chime in if you're using one of those.

Comment: Agree! That all sounds like a job for webform_civicrm!